# Algorithms: Ruby solution timing out but Java isn't

Tags: java, ruby, algorithm, time-complexity

I have the following two solutions for the following algo problem:

```
Suppose you have N integers from 1 to N. We define a beautiful
arrangement as an array that is constructed by these N numbers
successfully if one of the following is true for the ith position (1 <=
i <= N) in this array:

The number at the ith position is divisible by i. 
i is divisible by the number at the ith position. Now given N, how many beautiful
arrangements can you construct? (N will be <= 15)
```

Here's the provided solution in Java:

```
public class Solution {
    int count = 0;
    public int countArrangement(int N) {
        boolean[] visited = new boolean[N + 1];
        calculate(N, 1, visited);
        return count;
    }
    public void calculate(int N, int pos, boolean[] visited) {
        if (pos > N)
            count++;
        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
            if (!visited[i] && (pos % i == 0 || i % pos == 0)) {
                visited[i] = true;
                calculate(N, pos + 1, visited);
                visited[i] = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my Ruby solution:

```
def count_arrangement(n)
    visited = Array.new(n + 1) # zero index left blank
    count_arrangements(n, visited, 1)[:arrangements]
end

def count_arrangements(n, visited, i)
    return { arrangements: 1, recursed: true } if i == n + 1 # this is end of one arrangement
    max_arrangements = 0
    recursed = false

    1.upto(n) do |num|
        next if visited[num]
        if num % i == 0 || i % num == 0
            recursed = true
            this_visited = visited.dup
            this_visited[num] = true
            arrangements_obj = count_arrangements(n, this_visited, i + 1) # recursive depth only goes up to O(N)
            if arrangements_obj[:recursed]
              max_arrangements += arrangements_obj[:arrangements]
            end
        end
    end
    recursed ? { arrangements: max_arrangements, recursed: true } : { arrangements: -1, recursed: false }
end
```

Seems like the algorithmic complexity is the same (AFAIK), and yet my Ruby solution times out where the Java one doesn't. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: maybe one of the important lines is `this_visited = visited.dup` - you are completely cloning the `this_visited` array *every single time* you call `count_arrangements`

Comment: You think it's a matter of a higher constant factor?

Comment: could be? try doing what you did in Java. It could be that the constant factor this introduces overshadows the rest of the algorithm

Comment: Can you provide more details, at what number the Ruby implementation times out and Java doesn't? What is your Ruby version? Does it time out or appears to (you had to kill it with ^C)?